# Button/checkbox conditionally in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, jcheckbox

I am making a library system for a school project. In my search function, I have a SQL query which is outputted into a Result Set which is then used to create a DefaultTableModel which in turn is used to update the table and show the search results.

The code for this searching is below:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Search 
{
    private final String searchTerm, fileDir, table, defOrder;
    private String condition;
    private final String [] bookColumnNames;
    private final boolean showLoaned, showDistinct;

    public Search(String term, String dir, String tbl, String order, boolean showLoan, boolean distinct)
    {
        this.bookColumnNames = new String[]{"Title", "Author", "Genre", "ISBN", "Checkout"};
        searchTerm = term;
        fileDir = dir;
        table = tbl;
        showLoaned = showLoan;
        showDistinct = !distinct;
        defOrder = order;
    }

    DefaultTableModel searchBooks()
    {
        DefaultTableModel res = new DefaultTableModel();

        for (String columnName : bookColumnNames) 
        {
            res.addColumn(columnName);
        }

        if(isISBN(searchTerm))condition = "ISBN LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*'";
        else if(showLoaned)condition = "Title LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*' OR Author LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*' OR Genre LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*'";
        else condition = "(Title LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*' OR Author LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*' OR Genre LIKE '" + searchTerm + "*') AND Loaned = No";

        String defaultQuery;
        if(showDistinct) defaultQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT Title, Author, Genre, ISBN from " + table + " WHERE " + condition + " " + defOrder + ";";
        else defaultQuery = "SELECT Title, Author, Genre, ISBN from " + table + " WHERE " + condition + " " + defOrder + ";";

        ResultSet resSet = search(defaultQuery);

        int columns = 4;

        try
        {
            while (resSet.next()) 
            {
                Object[] row = new Object[columns];
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {  
                    row[i - 1] = resSet.getObject(i);
                }

                res.insertRow(resSet.getRow()-1,row);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        }

        return res;
    }

    ResultSet search(String defQuery)
    {
        ResultSet res = null;
        try
        {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + fileDir);
            PreparedStatement prepState = connection.prepareStatement(defQuery);
            res = prepState.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return res;
    }

    private boolean isISBN(String term)
    {
        boolean check = true;

        if(term.length() == 13)
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= term.length(); i++)
            {
                if(!Character.isDigit(term.charAt(i - 1)))
                {
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;
        }

        return check;
    }
```

The code for updating the table is here:

```
private void searchBarButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                                
        search = new Search(searchBar.getText(), config.get("databaseFileDirectory"),"tblBooks", config.get("defaultBookSort"), showLoaned.isSelected(), showDistinct.isSelected());
        DefaultTableModel model = search.searchBooks();
        searchResults.setModel(model);

        numSearchResults.setText(model.getRowCount() + " result(s) found");
}
```

Is there any way to place a button/checkbox in the last column of the table depending on if the book is loaned or not? If so, how would I make this button function in a way that I can add that specific table entry to a 2d object array or a list to create a cart? This button/checkbox should be placed in the "Checkout" column.

I do apologize if my method is inefficient/badly thought out. I am only around 1.5 years into Java dev and this is my first major project. Any suggestions in terms of logic solutions or actual code will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: "...SQL query which is outputted into a ResultSet which is then used to create a DefaultTableModel"  You missed a step.  Your ResultSet should be mapped to plain Java classes that make up your application model.  The application model then feeds the Default Table Model.  This allows you to transform the SQL data into presentation forms, like a JCheckbox.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc So I would need to implement a class within my Search class which extends AbstractTableModel and go through that whole workflow? I read up about that method and I wasn't too sure if I would need it. Will try to figure it out and will post an update if need further assistance. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: No.  Your application model class does not implement or extend any other class.  It stands alone.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have been doing some research but I cannot find a concrete explanation of what exactly you are referring to. Could you possibly elaborate as to what the application model is and how it should interact with other classes.

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a library system for a school project.

When tackling a large Java application, one way to simplify the coding is to use a [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  By separating the concerns, you can focus on one part of the application at a time.

Ok, I'm going to make some assumptions.  Let's assume that a library has books.

So, let's create a class to hold a book.  This class is a plain Java class.  It has nothing to do with Swing or any kind of GUI.  It's completely independent.  We call this a model class.

This class is part of the application model.  There will be other classes to describe other aspects of a library,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Book {

    private final String title;
    private final String isbn;

    private List<String> author;
    private List<String> genre;

    public Book(String title, String isbn) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.author = new ArrayList<>();
        this.genre = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void addAuthor(String author) {
        this.author.add(author);
    }

    public List<String> getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void addGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre.add(genre);
    }

    public List<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

}
```

In Java, class names are TitleCase.  Method names and field names are camelCase.

Everything in the `Book` class has to do with a book.  To have a collection of books, we'll create a `List<Book>` in a different model class.

A book has one title.  It could have a subtitle, but I chose not to include a subtitle field.  You can add a subtitle field if you want.

A book has one or more authors.

A book has one ISBN code.

A book can be placed in one or more genres.

Now, we still need to model patrons.  That would logically be a `Patron` class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Patron {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    private List<Book> checkedOut;

    public Patron(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.checkedOut = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public List<Book> getCheckedOut() {
        return checkedOut;
    }

    public void addCheckedOut(Book checkedOut) {
        this.checkedOut.add(checkedOut);
    }

    public void removeCheckedOut(Book returned) {
        this.checkedOut.remove(returned);
    }
}
```

I think you get the idea of an application model.

First, create the complete application model.

Second, from the application model, create your SQL tables.  Create an `SQL` class that holds all of the SQL code.  I didn't see enough of your code to create an `SQL` class for you.

Third, create the Swing GUI.  You can use Swing default models for this step.

Here's one of my SQL classes to give you an idea of how you should code your SQL class.  I'm using MySQL.  You should always use prepared statements to prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection).

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.amazon.ask.model.User;
import com.ggl.bible.reader.model.Book;
import com.ggl.bible.reader.model.Verse;
import com.ggl.bible.reader.model.VerseKey;

public class SQL {

    private Connection connection;

    public boolean connect() {
        try {
            String[] params = createConnectionStrings();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(params[0], 
                    params[1], params[2]);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String[] createConnectionStrings() {
        String[] connection = new String[3];
        String host = "bible-database.caaitaoyrsgp.us-east-1."
                + "rds.amazonaws.com";
        String port = "3306";
        String user = "ggleblanc";
        String useSSL = "?useSSL=false";
        String schema = "/bible";
        String password = "******************";
        String driver = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port;
        driver += schema + useSSL;
        connection[0] = driver;
        connection[1] = user;
        connection[2] = password;
        return connection;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Optional<Timestamp> selectLastCreated() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `timestamp` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`lastCreated` ");
        builder.append("    ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC ");
        builder.append("    LIMIT 0, 1; ");
        String sql = builder.toString();

        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            Optional<Timestamp> timestamp = Optional.of(
                    rs.getTimestamp(1));
            rs.close();
            return timestamp;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Optional.empty();
        }

    }

    public List<Book> selectBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `bookId`, `bookShortName`, ");
        builder.append("    `bookName` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`book`; ");
        String sql = builder.toString();

        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int bookID = rs.getInt("bookID");
                String bookShortName = rs.getString(
                        "bookShortName");
                String bookName = rs.getString("bookName");
                Book book = new Book(bookID, bookShortName, 
                        bookName);
                books.add(book);
            }
            rs.close();
            return books;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<Book>();
        }
    }

    public int selectLastChapter(int bookID) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT MAX(`chapter`) ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`verse` ");
        builder.append("    WHERE `bookID` = ? ");
        String sql = builder.toString();

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, bookID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            int result = rs.getInt(1);
            rs.close();
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public int selectLastVerse(int bookID, int chapter) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT MAX(`verse`) ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`verse` ");
        builder.append("    WHERE `bookID` = ? ");
        builder.append("    AND `chapter` = ? "); 
        String sql = builder.toString();

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, bookID);
            statement.setInt(2, chapter);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            int result = rs.getInt(1);
            rs.close();
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public List<Verse> selectPassage(VerseKey startVerseKey, 
            VerseKey endVerseKey) {
        List<Verse> verses = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] sql = new String[2];

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `verseID` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`verse` ");
        builder.append("    WHERE `bookID` = ? ");
        builder.append("    AND `chapter` = ? "); 
        builder.append("    AND `verse` = ?; ");
        sql[0] = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `bookID`, `chapter`, `verse`, "
                + "`text` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`verse` "); 
        builder.append("    WHERE `verseID` BETWEEN ? AND ? "); 
        sql[1] = builder.toString();

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql[0]);
            statement.setInt(1, startVerseKey.getBookID());
            statement.setInt(2, startVerseKey.getChapter());
            statement.setInt(3, startVerseKey.getVerse());
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return verses;
            }
            int startIndex = rs.getInt("verseID");
            rs.close();

            statement.setInt(1, endVerseKey.getBookID());
            statement.setInt(2, endVerseKey.getChapter());
            statement.setInt(3, endVerseKey.getVerse());
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return verses;
            }
            int endIndex = rs.getInt("verseID");
            rs.close();

            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql[1]);
            statement.setInt(1, startIndex);
            statement.setInt(2, endIndex);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int bookID = rs.getInt("bookID");
                int chapter = rs.getInt("chapter");
                int verseNum = rs.getInt("verse");
                String text = rs.getString("text");
                Verse verse = new Verse(bookID, chapter, 
                        verseNum, text);
                verses.add(verse);
            }
            rs.close();
            return verses;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<Verse>();
        }
    }

    public Optional<Verse> selectNextVerse(VerseKey verseKey) {
        String[] sql = new String[2];

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `verseID` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`verse` ");
        builder.append("    WHERE `bookID` = ? ");
        builder.append("    AND `chapter` = ? "); 
        builder.append("    AND `verse` = ?; ");
        sql[0] = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `bookID`, `chapter`, "
                + "`verse`, `text` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`verse` "); 
        builder.append("    WHERE `verseID` = ? "); 
        sql[1] = builder.toString();

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql[0]);
            statement.setInt(1, verseKey.getBookID());
            statement.setInt(2, verseKey.getChapter());
            statement.setInt(3, verseKey.getVerse());
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return Optional.empty();
            }
            int verseID = rs.getInt("verseID");
            rs.close();

            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql[1]);
            statement.setInt(1, verseID + 1);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return Optional.empty();
            }
            int bookID = rs.getInt("bookID");
            int chapter = rs.getInt("chapter");
            int verseNum = rs.getInt("verse");
            String text = rs.getString("text");
            Verse verse = new Verse(bookID, chapter, 
                    verseNum, text);
            rs.close();
            return Optional.of(verse);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public int selectVisitCount(User user) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `numberOfVisits` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`archive` "); 
        builder.append("    WHERE `userID` = ?; ");
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, userID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return -1;
            }
            int result = rs.getInt(1);
            rs.close();
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public int[] selectPassageChapter(User user) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `passageBookID`, "
                + "`passageChapter`, ");
        builder.append("       `passageVerse` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`archive` "); 
        builder.append("    WHERE `userID` = ?; ");
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            int[] output = {-1, -1, -1};
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, userID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return output;
            }
            output[0] = rs.getInt("passageBookID");
            output[1] = rs.getInt("passageChapter");
            output[2] = rs.getInt("passageVerse");
            rs.close();
            return output;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            int[] output = {-1, -1, -1};
            return output;
        }
    }

    public int[] selectReadingChapter(User user) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT `readingBookID`, "
                + "`readingChapter`, ");
        builder.append("       `readingStartVerse`, "
                + "`readingEndVerse` ");
        builder.append("    FROM `bible`.`archive` "); 
        builder.append("    WHERE `userID` = ?; ");
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            int[] output = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, userID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                rs.close();
                return output;
            }
            output[0] = rs.getInt("readingBookID");
            output[1] = rs.getInt("readingChapter");
            output[2] = rs.getInt("readingStartVerse");
            output[3] = rs.getInt("readingEndVerse");
            rs.close();
            return output;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            int[] output = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
            return output;
        }
    }

    public void insertArchiveRow(User user) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("INSERT INTO `bible`.`archive` "); 
        builder.append("    (`archiveID`, `numberOfVisits`, "); 
        builder.append("    `readingBookID`, `readingChapter`, "); 
        builder.append("    `readingStartVerse`, "
                + "`readingEndVerse`, ");
        builder.append("    `passageBookID`, "); 
        builder.append("    `passageChapter`, `passageVerse`, "); 
        builder.append("    `lastVisitTimeStamp`, `userID`) "); 
        builder.append("VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, "
                + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ");
        builder.append("    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?); "); 
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, 1);
            statement.setInt(2, 0);
            statement.setInt(3, 0);
            statement.setInt(4, 0);
            statement.setInt(5, 0);
            statement.setInt(6, 0);
            statement.setInt(7, 0);
            statement.setInt(8, 0);
            statement.setString(9, userID);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateVisitCount(User user) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("UPDATE `bible`.`archive` ");  
        builder.append("SET `numberOfVisits` = "
                + "`numberOfVisits` + 1, ");
        builder.append("    `lastVisitTimestamp` = "
                + "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ");
        builder.append("WHERE `userID` = ? "); 
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, userID);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public void updatePassageChapter(User user, 
            VerseKey verseKey) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("UPDATE `bible`.`archive` ");  
        builder.append("SET `passageBookID` = ?, "); 
        builder.append("    `passageChapter` = ?, "); 
        builder.append("    `passageVerse` = ? "); 
        builder.append("WHERE `userID` = ? "); 
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, verseKey.getBookID());
            statement.setInt(2, verseKey.getChapter());
            statement.setInt(3, verseKey.getVerse());
            statement.setString(4, userID);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateReadingChapter(User user, 
            VerseKey verseKey, int endVerse) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("UPDATE `bible`.`archive` ");  
        builder.append("SET `readingBookID` = ?, "); 
        builder.append("    `readingChapter` = ?, "); 
        builder.append("    `readingStartVerse` = ?, "); 
        builder.append("    `readingEndVerse` = ? "); 
        builder.append("WHERE `userID` = ? "); 
        String sql = builder.toString();
        String userID = user.getUserId();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, verseKey.getBookID());
            statement.setInt(2, verseKey.getChapter());
            statement.setInt(3, verseKey.getVerse());
            statement.setInt(4, endVerse);
            statement.setString(5, userID);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has really helped me out a lot.